# Airflow GCSToGCSOperator regex

Tags: airflow

I am trying to use the GCSToGCSOperator operator to copy files from one GCS bucket to another. However, I only need to copy files with a certain regex that are follow this path: **abcd**.csv such as `134_abcd_2023.csv`

Based on Airflow docs, I can use `*` on my `source_object` argument, this is one example provided by Airflow:

```
copy_files = GCSToGCSOperator(
    task_id='copy_files',
    source_bucket='data',
    source_object='sales/sales-2017/*.avro',
    destination_bucket='data_backup',
    destination_object='copied_sales/2017/',
    gcp_conn_id=google_cloud_conn_id
)
```

Would it be possible to do something like this?

```
copy_files = GCSToGCSOperator(
    task_id='copy_files',
    source_bucket='data',
    source_object='*_abcd_*.csv',
    destination_bucket='data_backup',
    destination_object='copied_sales/2017/',
    gcp_conn_id=google_cloud_conn_id
)
```

Answer (score 0):

source_object parameter allows only one wildcard for objects (filenames). The wildcard can appear inside the object name or at the end of the object name.

you can use source_objects (plural) as a collection parameter instead of source_object. However you can only have one * as stated above. If possible change the naming convention to wildcard the end of the filename.

ie:

> source_objects = ['abcd_*.csv'],

Please refer to [Airflow docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/gcs_to_gcs/index.html)